# TypeAhead and Bloodhound only searching on first words in JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm using TypeAhead to provide autocomplete results for a textbox. But it seems either Bloodhound or TypeAhead is only searching on the first words of found in the JSON array I'm providing.

The JSON looks as follows:

```
[
    {
        "name": "ALICE",
        "value": "ALICE",
        "physical_address": "ERF 270 CNR. OF THOMPSON AND INTWANA STREET, ALICE",
        "province": "PROVINCE",
        "tokens": [
            "ALICE",
            "PROVINCE",
            "ERF",
            "270",
            "CNR.",
            "OF",
            "THOMPSON",
            "AND",
            "INTWANA",
            "STREET",
            "ALICE"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "BUTTERWORTH",
        "value": "BUTTERWORTH",
        "physical_address": "SHOP NO. 1 MASONIC SHOPPING COMP, COR HIGH & BELL STREET BUTTERWORTH 4960",
        "province": "PROVINCE",
        "tokens": [
            "BUTTERWORTH",
            "PROVINCE",
            "SHOP",
            "NO.",
            "1",
            "MASONIC",
            "SHOPPING",
            "COMP",
            "COR",
            "HIGH",
            "&",
            "BELL",
            "STREET",
            "BUTTERWORTH",
            "4960"
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm intialising TypeAhead as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="films">
    <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" placeholder="Search" name="films" autocomplete="off" id="search">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
/* TypeAhead invoked */
var _prefetch_url = $root_path + '/media/mod_storelocator/stores_json.php';

// constructs the suggestion engine
var films = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 15,
    prefetch: _prefetch_url
});

// kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
films.initialize();

$('.films .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey : 'value',
    source: films.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
            '<p class="repo-language">{{province}}</p>',
            '<p class="repo-name">{{name}}</p>',
            '<p class="repo-description">{{physical_address}}</p>'
        ].join(''))
    }
});
```

I'd really appreciate any help/pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You were passing in `d.value` into the datumTokenizer, so it was using just the value object from each element in the array.

Note also that Bloodhound tokenizes the data itself, so you don't need to pass back the individual tokens in your JSON (i.e. you don't need the `tokens` object).

So I would change it to use Bloodhound to tokenize the `value` and the `physical_address` objects combined of each element in the array:

```
// constructs the suggestion engine
var films = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { 
                      return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); 
                    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 15,
    prefetch: {
       url: _prefetch_url,
       filter: function(list) {
          return $.map(list, 
                 function(element) { 
                         return { name: element.value + " " + element.physical_address }; 
                 });
       }
    }
});
```

Have only been able to test this in a local context with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/fLuzu9hc/3/), but the prefetch should work the same way.

Comment: Thank for you time, but I still can't type in any other words than BUTTERWORTH, SHOP or PROVINCE, otherwise the autocomplete stops and returns nothing.

Comment: Sorry, but there must be something wrong in your code. [See this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CktkgrbItUSGMsjln6ox?p=preview). It works fine for me with prefetch.